# How to run useEffect conditionally that depends on the state from the same cycle

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, react-hooks, race-condition

I have a sequence of events that has to happen with one of the events relying on the execution of the previous event.

```
const [token, setToken] = useState('')
const getToken = async () => {
    try {
        const newToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem(LOGIN_TOKEN)
        setToken(newToken)
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(err)
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
    getToken()
    if(token) {
        console.log("the final event")
    }
}, [postAction])
```

I have the `useEffect` hook that runs every time `postAction` changes. I want the "final event" to happen only if `getToken` runs and retrieves the `token`. 
I believe the asynchronous nature of the `setToken` setter is not happening in time for the `token` to be set in order to meet the condition of the `if statement`. Therefore, the final event never gets executed on the first run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add another `useEffect` hook that specifically looks for changes to the token.

```
useEffect(() => {
  getToken();
}, [postAction]);

useEffect(() => {
  if(token) {
    console.log("the final event")
  }
}, [token]);
```

Comment: , [token || postAction]   What's mean in useEffect ?

Comment: @DevAS that's the dependency array for the hook. The hook will run any time a variable in the dependency array is updated.

Comment: Hmm, If i want to use componentDidMount, that's array Equals what in didMount?

Comment: It's more like `componentDidUpdate` where you can compare previous to current props and take action based on that comparison.